# How can I import this data and export it to an excel file?

Tags: matlab

I have 672 samples like these in a .txt file:

```
{    
sleep:1360.36,  
eat:4.36,  
live:16.37,  
travel:22.18,  
work:22,  
school:0.84,  
vt:386.87  
},
```

I want to put them in an excel file where `{sleep, eat, live, travel, work, school, vt}` are represented in a row and each sample represented in columns, with the correspondent number matching each. I've never dealt with text files following this format on matlab so I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: wait, so you want to export this to a csv (i.e. that excel can open)? Or do you want to import them into Matlab, I am confused. Your row delimiter is "," and column delimiter is ":", you can put it into excel by setting the delimiters, or into matlab using `textscan` or `dmlread`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to export them into a .csv and thought the best way to do it would be through matlab. I thought this because this is data from 15 to 15 minutes during one week and I wanted to turn them into 1 hour samples by averaging them in groups of 4 (sorry if this sounds complicated). Is this possible or too complex?

Comment: No it is not too complex. However, some evidence of original effort is usually expected. Do a little research on opening and reading portion of a file in loop. Put something together and if you run into trouble, come back and edit your question to include your code, the error(s) you are receiving and where the errors are occurring.

Comment: You can also directly put cell arrays into Excel files using xlswrite. It doesn't get much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

very possible, you can do it in Matlab if you are familiar with it (although it is also quite easy to do in excel). To load in your file (no need to convert it, Matlab reads txt Files). you can do something like:

```
fileID = fopen('test2.txt'); %//Your file name
Input = textscan(fileID,'%s %f','Delimiter',':');
GoodRows = find(~isnan(Input{2} ));
column1 = Input{1}(GoodRows,:); //Column 1 is in the format of Cells (since you are storing Strings
column2 = Input{2}(GoodRows,:); //Column 2 is in the format of a Matrix, which will allow you to take numbers and do averages etc.
```

The cell and the matrix share indexes, so you can reformat your data eventually in to a Cell and export it in Matlab.

```
column1 = 

'sleep'
'eat'
'live'
'travel'
'work'
'school'
'vt'

column2 =
```

1.0e+003 *

```
1.3604
0.0044
0.0164
0.0222
0.0220
0.0008
0.3869
```

==============EDIT===============
If you have multiple columns after the String, i.e.:
  sleep,1.5,1.4,1.3

If you want to keep using textscan, you will need to specify how many columns there are. This is done by either:

```
 Input = textscan(fileID,'%s %f %f %f %f','Delimiter',':'); //% add %f for each numeric column.
```

Or

```
 Input = textscan(fileID,'%s repmat('%f',[1,N])]','Delimiter',':'); %// where N is the number of numeric columns you have.
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I tried your advice but it is not recognizing column1 as the same after it goes to the next sample:

Example of what I get:
sleep, eat, live, travel, work, school, vt, sleep, eat, live, travel, work, school, vt, sleep, eat, live, travel, work, school, vt, 

I only want this variables to be recognized once so I get sort of a table like this:
    sleep    eat      live     travel  work       school  vt   
1   1.36  0.044  0.164 0.0222  0.0220 0.0008 0.3869    
2  
3  
4  
5  
  
where 1,2,3,4,5 are the samples. Hope I made myself clear

Comment: I posted this comment as an answer so it is better understandable

Comment: @JoãoFrancisco Updated the answer to include multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from Excel into Matlab using `xlsread` and export data using `xlswrite`. See the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)

Syntax

```
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

where `A` might be a cell array where the cells contain number of strings, `sheet` is the name of the Excel sheet and `xlRange` is the range in the Excel sheet (example: A1:B5).

Code example:

```
A = {'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'; 1, 2, 3};
xlswrite('example.xls', A, 'ExampleSheet', 'A1:B3');
```

Some hints:

- If you know the number of rows and columsn of your data only at runtime but still want to give a range you must somehow assemble the range string yourself (rows are easy with sprintf, column names are more difficult (A, B, C, .., Z, AA, AB, ...))
- If you do not have Excel on your computer, you will get csv files (see documentation)
- Although each call to `xlswrite` returns quite fast, the system is still working. If another call to `xlswrite` comes too soon you might get unexpected (delay dependent) errors with no way to avoid them then to wait for sufficient time. I usually collect my data and then write everything to an excel file in one go.